# How to disable keyboard in Phonegap/Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, keyboard

I'm creating a aplication with cordova/phonegap and I need to disable the keyboard even when I'm inside a textbox. I dont want the keyboard appears in any situation.
The application has a textbox that occupies most of the window. Below is a zone of buttons that are right for putting text inside the textbox.

If I put the textbox 'readonly' the keyboard dont appear but I need to see where the pointer is currently located.

Mi apllication is for Android.

Thanks very very much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use soft keyboard to hide it. It is available at github all you have to do is put in this code after the plugin soft keyboard has been added:

```
plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function () {
// success
 },function () {
// fail
});
```

Or/And you could add or change the meta tag in your head tags of html to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

If you don't want to run the keyboard at all  during the app just remove the plugin and don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use this plugins but when I call the function that does the "hide", the keyboard disappears but reappears in the same instant. I call the function in the onclick of the textbox. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: The metas are exactly like this. What I need is that "SoftKeyBoard.hide" run at all time to be on the TextBox without keyboard

Comment: But if I remove the plugin, I cannot hide the keyboard. I need hide keyboard when touch in textbox but with this plugin the keyboard disappears but reappears in the same instant.

Comment: Remove the plugin and don't use hide. There is no reason the keyboard should appear. Make sure you don't have any graphic icons etc of the keyboard in the app.